# Why is openam redirecting to the wrong URL?

Tags: openam

I am following a tutorial on setting up realms.
I am protecting the URL http://fec.example.com:80 with a apache web agent pointing to my openam server.
When I access http://fec.example.com:80 I expect it to go to

http://subscribers.example.com:18080/openam/XUI/?goto=http%3A%2F%2Ffec.example.com%3A80%2F#login/

But instead it goes to:
http://subscribers.example.com:18080/openam/XUI/?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fopenam.example.com%3A18080%2Fopenam%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_mode%3Dform_post%26state%3D704b6f90-af10-214e-92bb-61b2ab1d05e5%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffec.example.com%253A80%252Fagent%252Fcdsso-oauth2%26response_type%3Did_token%26scope%3Dopenid%26client_id%3Dwebagent%26agent_provider%3Dtrue%26agent_realm%3D%252Fsubscribers%26nonce%3D6F8D1B2B7D3EDD5547812671C2415BAB&realm=%2F#login/

Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This means you are using Agent version 5 and this is now using OIDC to achieve SSO. Please have a look at the docs.